# Steam Workshop - can I save a collection of subscribed items?

Tags: steam, steam-workshop

I play Cities:Skylines and I have 800+ subscribed-to items in the workshop. I haven't played for a while (2 new expansions since) and I would like to do a "clean slate" of my subscriptions and start anew.

But I want to save my current set of subscriptions somewhere so that I can 1. revert back if I want and 2. browse old subscribed items that I want to include again in the future.

So I was looking for a "save all subscriptions to profile" button on Steam, so that I could load different profiles of mods. Is there such an inbuilt feature and if not, are there / what are potential work-arounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is:

Go to **Community** -> **Workshop**, 

choose your game using '**Search for a Workshop**' found on the right side of the menu, 

select **Browse** -> **Collections**, 

and in the top right you can find a button '**Create Collection**'.

Here you can save a current set or a selection of favourited items, or create a new set.

[image: Steam screenshot, showing the first two steps]
[image: Steam screenshot, showing the third step]
[image: Steam screenshot, showing the fourth step]
<sup>Third screenshot showing a different game because I don't own Cities: Skylines, hence the button isn't shown</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I should add for anyone else reading, the following menu for creating your collection does not feature an "add all" button so you have to scroll through and click every single subscribed item in order to add it.